# wordpressの同じサーバー内ドメイン変更について

Tags: wordpress

さくらインターネットのレンタルサーバーを使っていてマルチドメイン設定をしています。(1つのサーバーにaaaとbbbのドメインを設定しています。aaaのドメイン内の1つのフォルダをbbbドメインで指定しています。)

wordpressをaaaドメインのhttp://aaa/wp/にインストールしました。 
これをbbbドメインhttp://bbb/で表示できるように、また変更してwordpressが正常に動作するようにしたい場合です。

①さくらインターネットのマルチドメイン設定でbbbドメインにwpフォルダを設定する。 
②wordpressの一般設定のwordpressアドレスとサイトアドレスをhttp://bbb/に設定する。

上記①②で、wordpressをhttp://bbb/に変更またwordpressを正常に動作できますでしょうか？

ドメインやサーバー、wordpressのことがまだまだわかっていません。 
分かりづらくてすみませんが、教えて頂けますでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1,2の変更に加えて投稿記事に挿入した画像URLにもフルパスURLが書き込まれていますので、
投稿記事内のURLも変更する必要があります。

記事内のURL置換をするには、「DATABASE SEARCH AND REPLACE SCRIPT IN PHP」を使用すると良いでしょう。

２の変更は、wordpressで使用している全テーブルを一括置換すると必要ないかもしれません。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。①②の他にURLの変更が必要なのですね。DATABASE SEARCH AND REPLACE SCRIPT IN PHPを調べて作業を行ってみたいと思います。